# Save mouse coordinate in an array

Tags: javascript

I want to get mouse coordinate in an array. Also I click anywhere I can't get mouse coordinate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Google Maps</title>
    <style>body {background-color: ivory;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p id="results">result</p>
    <script>
    var x = document.getElementById("body");
    var offsetX = x.offsetLeft;
    var offsetY = x.offsetTop;
    x.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
    function handleClick(e) {
      mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
      mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You clicked at: " + mouseX + "/" + mouseY;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there something specific you are having trouble with? not sure I understand your question (if there is one)

Comment: There is no element in your HTML with `id="body"`.

Comment: And - what does this have to do with jQuery? Looks like vanilla JavaScript to me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no element within your HTML that has `id="body"`. You can access the `<body>` element using `document.body`.

Also, the body is rather small since it only contains your one `<p>` element, so you may want to add some css so that you can click anywhere in the window and your event will fire:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

To store the calculated coordinates in an array, just create a blank array:

```
var coords = [];
```

Then add coordinates to them:

```
coords.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var x = document.body;
var offsetX = x.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = x.offsetTop;
x.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

var coords = [];

function handleClick(e) {
  mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);  
  coords.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You have clicked at: " + JSON.stringify(coords);
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<p id="results">result</p>
```

Comment: didnt work. I want to save clicked coordinates in an array.

Answer (score 2):

This would be how I approach it.

You have no element with an `id` of `body` so I created one with an id of `bodyEquivalent`

If you want to get an actual tag, you need to use 
`getElementsByTagName('tag_name');` which returns an array of matching elements (you can grab the first element from the array)

or more simply: `document.body` for the `body` tag

```js
var x = document.getElementById("bodyEquivalent");
// or 
// var x = document.body;

var offsetX = x.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = x.offsetTop;
x.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// array to store click coords
var clickCoords = [];

// a point coord
var ClickPoint = function(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
};

ClickPoint.prototype.toString = function(){
   return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
}

function handleClick(e) {
  mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);

  // create click point and store it in array
  var aClick = new ClickPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
  clickCoords.push(aClick);

  // update results
  showArrayCoords(clickCoords);
}

function showArrayCoords(coords) {
  var innerHtml = 'You clicked at:<br/>';
  for (i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    innerHtml += coords[i] + "<br/>";
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = innerHtml;
}
```

```css
#bodyEquivalent {
  background-color: ivory;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bodyEquivalent">
</div>
<p id="results">result</p>
```